# Source for Ritva's quote

Tags: sources-mekorot, ritva

The Ritva allegedly said:

> And if a heretic of the disciples of Jesus should murmur to you saying that since the commandments are annulled in the future, this means the Torah was given only for a finite period of time, and therefore Jesus was able to add to and delete from it, say to him that only one who is afraid could say this.

In which book does he say this; where is the original quote from?

Comment: Where is this alleged?

Comment: The response doesn't seem responsive.